# Django + GAE + Google Cloud SQL authentication issue in Windows

Tags: django, windows, google-app-engine, oauth, google-cloud-sql

I've followed all [steps](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django) required to configure Django with GAE + Google Cloud SQL (on Windows 7) but I am unable to authenticate (OAuth2) and run syncdb remotely. When I run manage.py syncdb the browser pops up and I am requested to allow access, but when I do that nothing happens. The browser is forwarded correctly to my local django instalation (the typical It worked! screen) but no OAuth2 token is in %USERPROFILE%\ and the console gets frozen:

```
C:\Users\me\myproject>python manage.py syncdb
Your browser has been opened to visit:

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?state=None&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&response_type=code&client_id=my_id.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fsqlservice&access_type=offline

If your browser is on a different machine then exit and re-run this
application with the command-line parameter

  --noauth_local_webserver
```

There is no error message and I have to kill the console.

Anybody has faced a similar issue? Is there any log somewhere in GAE I can check?

Comment: Well, apparently everything is working fine today.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, only on OS X.

I never figured out why, but it went away after a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but it was because I had local appengine server running while I was running manage.py syncdb. Shutting it down and trying again worked as intended.

hope that helps.